# python threading start/stop

Tags: python, function, python-multithreading

I am trying to implement a start/stop function in my code.

For simplicity lets assume I have two functions:

```
def setup():
    global start_process
    # setting up some parameters with user inputs
    actual_process()

def actual_process():
    global start_process, continue_process
    start_process = True
    while start_process:

        continue_process = True

        thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=start_stop)
        thread_1.daemon = True 
        thread_1.start()

        # do something infinitely


def start_stop():
    global continue_process, start_process
    while continue_process:
        user_input = input('Press "r" to restart or "s" to stop: ')
        if user_input == 's':
            continue_process = False
            start_process = False
            print('closing program')

        if user_input == 'r':
            continue_process = False
            start_process = False
            print('Restarting')
            setup()

setup()
```

But when I enter 's' or 'r' the function start_stop is quitting but the while loop of actual_process() keeps running without stopping. It however launches setup(). But since actual_process() doesn't stop, I can not reset the parameters.

So my question would be, how can I change my code that the while loop stops ?

Comment: Read up on [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Comment: You're setting `global continue_processing`, with `ing`, but check `while continue_process`, without `ing`, so when you do `continue_process = False`, that change will not propagate to the global namespace

Comment: Sorry was written in a rush on a mobile phone correct now

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes :

- as Nearoo said, you had 2 different variables names `continue_process` and `continue_processing` with `ing`
- I added a call to `actual_process()` in `setup()`
- you forgot a quotation marks `'` in your `input(...)` line
- I added a `break`statement when it **stops**, so there is not another undesired loop

You can try this :

```
import threading

def setup():
    global start_process, count
    count = 0
    # setting up some parameters with user inputs
    # and call actual_process()
    actual_process()

def actual_process():
    global start_process, continue_processing, count
    start_process = True
    while start_process:

        continue_processing = True

        thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=start_stop)
        thread_1.daemon = True 
        thread_1.start()

        # do something infinitely

def start_stop():
    global continue_processing, start_process
    while continue_processing:
        user_input = input('Press "r" to restart or "s" to stop:')
        if user_input == 's':
            continue_processing = False
            start_process = False
            print('closing program')
            break

        if user_input == 'r':
            continue_processing = False
            start_process = False
            print('Restarting')
            setup()

setup()
```

**EDIT**
Now I do not call `setup()` when restarting, the global while loop `while start_process:` will do it automatically.

I also added an `example_of_process()` that increment a var `count` and prints it, just to simulate an infinite process that we can restart or stop.

Note that you need to press "r + Enter" to restart, and "s + Enter" to stop.

```
import threading
import time

def setup():
    global start_process 
    actual_process()

def actual_process():
    global start_process , continue_process, count
    start_process  = True
    count = 0
    while start_process :
        continue_process = True

        thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=start_stop)
        thread_1.daemon = True
        thread_1.start()

        example_of_process() # do something infinitely

def start_stop():
    global continue_process, start_process , count
    while continue_process:
        user_input = input('Press "r" + Enter to restart or "s" + Enter to stop: \n')
        if user_input == 's':
            continue_process = False
            start_process  = False
            print("closing program")
        if user_input == 'r':
            continue_process = False
            count = 0
            print("Restarting")

def example_of_process():
    global continue_process, count
    while continue_process:
        print("count", count)
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)

setup()
```

Comment: Sorry I was typing the question and code by hand on my mobile phone. The problem ist still the same, actual_process does not stop when I type r or s.

Comment: Can you check my **EDIT ** part ? I made some changes